# Morphology skeleton - differences betwen scikit-image, pymorph, OpenCV-Python?

Tags: python, scikit-image, morphological-analysis

I noticed significant differences in skeleton geometry between various python scientific graphics oriented packages.

Skeleton using OpenCV-Python:

[image: Skeleton using OpenCV-Python]

Skeleton using pymorph:

[image: Skeleton using pymorph]

Skeleton using scikit-image:

[image: Skeleton using scikit-image]

As one can observe OpenCV-Python and pymorph produce the same skeleton but scikit-image does not. What is the reason for skeletons' differences? Which one is proper skeleton?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These packages implement different algorithms.  The first two apply the [Medial Axis Transform](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/skeleton.htm) whereas scikit-image implements the method described in "[A fast parallel algorithm for thinning digital patterns](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.morphology.html#skimage.morphology.skeletonize)" by T. Y. Zhang and C. Y. Suen.  If you want the same behavior in scikit-image, try [skimage.morphology.medial_axis](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_medial_transform.html).

Comment: I found useful statement in link You had written. "Just as there are many different types of distance transform there are many types of skeletonization algorithm, all of which produce slightly different results."